# In NAnt, using the CSC task, how do I suppress compiler warnings?

Tags: nant, csc

I see the CSC task in NAnt has a *nowarn* attribute, but apparently this is deprecated. How can I suppress warnings then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the nowarn **element** instead. For example:

```
<csc output="${build.dir.legacy}Library.dll"
 target="library"
 verbose="${debug}">

  <sources basedir="${source.legacy.patterns.dir}">
    <include name="**.cs"/>
  </sources>

  <nowarn>
    <warning number="0162,0169,0168,0219,0414,0649,0114,0105"></warning>
  </nowarn>

</csc>
```